# Findall / FindAllAsync not working properly on android 4.1 jelly bean

Tags: android, webview

I have a small android app that haves a webview. In android 2.2, 2.3, I can perform a search on this webview using findAll and it works great, highlights the words being searched and scrolls to the position of the match.

In android 4.0.X, the search works and scrolls ok, but no highlight (using findAll).

In android 4.1, using findAll or findAllAsync, it doesn't really matter, the search doesn't work well at all. In my tests, it performs the search, but does not scroll to the position of the match, instead returning to the top of the page, which is ridiculous. It even highlights the match, but without going to the position on the webview it's as good as useless from a usability standpoint.

Here's the source codes:

```
//////////////////////////////
// for android 2.2, 2.3, 4.0.x
//////////////////////////////
myContent.findAll(findBox.getText().toString());
try{
    //Can't use getMethod() in android 4.0.3 as it's a private method
    for(Method m : WebView.class.getDeclaredMethods()){
        if(m.getName().equals("setFindIsUp")){
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(myContent, true);
            break;
        }
    }
}catch(Exception ignored){}
```

Then, on another method with target api 16:

```
/////////////////////////////
// for android 4.1
/////////////////////////////
myContent.findAllAsync(findBox.getText().toString());
try{
    //Can't use getMethod() in android 4.0.3 as it's a private method
    for(Method m : WebView.class.getDeclaredMethods()){
        if(m.getName().equals("setFindIsUp")){
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(myContent, true);
            break;
        }
    }
}catch(Exception ignored){}
```

Any ideas on how to make the search work on jelly bean? Thank you very much.

Comment: I search in a WebView with a similar code and it works well for me including Highlight of the searchresults.
I working on a Samsung Note 10.1 Tab with JB 4.1.1. Maybe an update would solve your problem.